# onsubmit validate password not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Okay, so lets get it out of the way that I've already referenced several other questions to see if they could help me so please don't bother me with possible duplicates unless you're a 100% certain that the duplicate can help me, thank you.

---

I have a form which has 2 password input fields and a submit button (and much more). I am trying to fire a `validate()` function `onsubmit` but for some reason the script just will not work. am I missing or overlooking something?

The `validate()` function should simply check if both password fields are identical values, if so: submit form, if not: don't submit and `alert("passwords do not match");`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){   //begin formulier

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h2 style="margin:3% 0 0 0;">Nieuwe medewerker Registreren</h2>

    <div style="float:right; margin:-3% 0 0 0;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default createBtn" onsubmit="return validate();" />
    </div>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Persoonlijke gegevens</h4><!--Begin Persoonlijke gegevens-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>wachtwoord</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="password" id="passphrase" class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-5"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>wachtwoord</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.wachtwoord, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "passphraseConf", @class = "form-control", required = "required", type = "password" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.wachtwoord, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
} <!--Einde formulier-->
```

I removed unnecessary inputs for the sake of keeping this short, if you would like to see the full page; [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/b8a08ae0/). **note:** I am working in asp.net with a database so if you RUN the jsfiddle, the page will look weird.

I've tried several jquery scripts but these 2 made the most sense to me that they should work;

1:

```
function validate() {
        alert("validating");
        var password = $("#passphrase").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#passphraseConf").val();
        return (password === confirmPassword) 
    }
```

2:

```
function validate() {
        alert("validating");
        var password = $("#passphrase").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#passphraseConf").val();
        if (password === confirmPassword) {
            return (true);
            alert("passwords valid");
        } else {
            return (false);
            alert('De wachtwoord velden komen niet overeen.');
        }
    }
```

but when I press the submit button neither scripts work. the alerts won't even fire and I don't understand why.

---

**additional information:**

jQuery version: 3.3.1

---

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Why are you not just using the `[Compare]` attribute and MVC's built in validation which will give you both client and server side validation

Comment: because I didnt know that even existed :D

Comment: [Client Side Password and Confirm Password validation in ASP.Net MVC using Data Annotations and jQuery](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Client-Side-Password-and-Confirm-Password-validation-in-ASPNet-MVC-using-Data-Annotations-and-jQuery.aspx) (doing this manually is crazy, and anyone can by pass that script - you must ALWAYS validate on the server)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using onsubmit you can use onclick for button

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("The form was submitted");
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: if you want to use onsubmit then you should use it in form tag

Comment: oh ffs... I feel like an idiot now. thank you. x) I will accept your answer when stackoverflow will allow me to

Comment: @FllnAngl,  i'm glad you noticed